# In angular 2 I cant route between child components without reloading

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

We have three components. The AppComponent contains two sub components namely LoginComponent and LandingPageComponent. @Rougeconfig has defined in AppComponent.  But unfortunately I can't route from Login to LandingPage.

**AppComponent**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import { RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from 'angular2/router';
import {LoginComponent} from '../app-components/login/login.component';
import {LandingPageComponent} from '../app-components/landing-page/landing-page.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'My-app',
    templateUrl: './app/app-components/app.html',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS]     
})
@RouteConfig([
  {
    path: '/login',
    name: 'Login',
    component: LoginComponent,
    useAsDefault: true
  },
  {
    path: '/landing-page',
    name: 'Landing-page',
    component: LandingPageComponent,
   }
])
export class AppComponent { }
```

**LoginComponet**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import { RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS, Router} from 'angular2/router';
import {NgForm}    from 'angular2/common';
import {LandingPageComponent} from '../landing-page/landing-page.component'

@Component({
    selector: 'login',
    template: '<a [routerLink]="['Landing-page']">Landing-page</a>',
    styleUrls:['./app/app-components/login/login.css'],
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS] 

})

export class LoginComponent { 

    //DECLARATIONS
   login={username:"",password:""} ; 
   active = true;
   submitted = false;
   router: Router;

   logineduser=logindec; 
   //constructor(private _router:Router) {}

  constructor(_router: Router){   
      this.router = _router;

   }
  onauth() { 
      this.submitted = true;
      if(this.logineduser.username==this.login.username&&this.logineduser.password==this.login.password){
         this.router.navigateByUrl('/landing-page');
         location.reload();
      }      
   }       
}

var logindec={
    username:"sampleuser",
    password:"a"
} ;
```

**LandingPageComponet**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'login',
    template:'<h1>Landing Page</h1>'
})
export class LandingPageComponent {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove

```
providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS]
```

from everywhere except your `AppComponent`

Comment: Thanks,
After some times, If we want to route from Sub component(X) to its own sub components (X1,X2....). 
How can we make it possible without adding [ROUTER_PROVIDERS] in  Sub component (X)

Comment: I don't understand the question. `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` should only be added to the root component and they are then available globally. Only `ROUTER_DIRECTIVES` need to be added to each component where `<router-outlet>` or `[routerLink] is used.

Comment: How can we route inside an child component 
can we write route config inside the child component for its sub component.

Comment: Sure, just add `@RouteConfig()` This should demonstrate it https://plnkr.co/edit/nt8Zzi?p=preview